# Match regex defined in text/config file against strings in database with filter/whitelist

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

The main thrust is "how do I take a list of regex strings, contained in a text file, and find all matches on a specific database column taking into account exclusions/whitelist".

Sample Text file:

```
[Bad 192 address]=192\.168\.(1|2)\.\d{1,3} / (192\.168\.(1|2)\.1)
[Bad 172 address]=172\.(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} / (172\.(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\.\d{1,3}\.1)
[Bad 10 address]=10\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} / (10\.0\.(0|120|250)\.1
```

In the above example, I have the name of the regex match in brackets, then the raw regex match, and finally the filter I wish to apply to this regex match in parenthesis separated from the original regex match with a "/".

I would like to point to a file containing regex matches structured similarly, and running them against a column within a table, or number of tables, in a database. In this example the idea is to find all private IP space matches that aren't whitelisted, and outputting the matches along with the associated signature's name. So a hit might look like "[Bad 192 address] 192.168.1.58".

Initially I was iterating through the file line-by-line, splitting each rule into an array of 3 items (the sig, the regex, and the filter), assigning them within a function to variables that I can work with and sending a SQL SELECT query per rule, trying to discard the whitelisted values from the returned matches but this isn't working reliably and is giving me terrible performance. For context, I need to be able to potentially iterate through 1 million rows, but I might be able reduce that value out-of-band into thousands of unique values.

Mainly concerned with the mechanism for taking defined regexe strings in File A, running them against Database B, discarding any whitelisted values, and spitting out the string match as well as the associated "signature".

Comment: And you don't have the slightest clue how to do any of those four things?

Comment: The question wasn't just how to do it, it's how to approach it efficiently. I described the approach I am currently using to address it, but again the desire is to be able to efficiently iterate through at least thousands, if not millions of rows for 15+ disctinct regex matches defined in a config file.

Comment: How are you doing the regex matches and the filtering? Show the code.